# Getting null value output after Transformation using Mule Datamapper

Tags: mule

I have a transformer component in Mule, that transform `xml` to `json`. But output json has null Object/Array

eg :-

```
"PublicRecord" : {
            "PostalAddress" : {
              "Municipality" : [ ]
            }
          },
          "RegistrySearch" : {
            "PostalAddress" : {
              "Municipality" : [ ]
            },
            "License" : {
              "LicenseAuthorityAddress" : {
                "Municipality" : [ ]
              }
            }
          },
```

How can I remove this null object in Transformation ?

Comment: May be you could add an "if" in the script view of datamapper to avoid transform input field "Municipality" if it's empty. Please share your mapping and/or your input/output files to dig a bit into the problem.

Comment: Did you figure this out? I am having the same issue - getting empty objects because I have a nested array property.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a cardinality problem. In datamapper you iterate over the input to generate output. Somehow you are performing an iteration that is not necessary. Review at the center-top of your dialog, the element mapping (you need to click on modify) and play with the nested mappings.